# Angular 16 - ERROR FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use firestore in my angular crud project, but when trying to add a new object to the database i get the error message "ERROR FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore", i double checked the code and i can't find out whats wrong, I'm using angular 16, firebase 10.3.1 and angular/fire 7.5.0

> ERROR FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, collection, addDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TesteService {
  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {}

  addData(user: any) {
    const collectionInstance = collection(this.firestore, 'users');
    addDoc(collectionInstance, user)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('It Worked!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error);
      });
  }
}
```

I think it might be related to some changes in the way you can do that in the most recent versions

Comment: Just going from what the error says, is a `Firestore` the same as a `FirebaseFirestore`?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem try

npm uninstall @angular/fire
npm uninstall firebase

then run

npm install firebase@latest @angular/fire@latest

It worked for me.

Comment: sadly not for me

Comment: @bastifix actually i had many problems using the firestore with Angular, the lack of content about the new ways of integrating it with Angular 16 using the angular/fire 7.5.0 made me give up on it, but i managed to implement firebase realtime database instead, it is much more simple and the implementation didnt change at all in the last years, so there is a plenty of code out there to help, if it fits your case and you 
occasionally have some problems, post here will be glad to help.

Comment: thanks for your offer! I've to stick with firestore because of offline functionality and queries... Maybe in the next weeks there will be some solutions^^